# How to pray while being observed and you are hiding your conversion from your family?

Tags: salat, conversion, non-muslim-countries, awrah

I embraced Islam recently thanks to Allah. I was brought up and am living now in a christian society, which is a very bad environment that hinders me from clinching to my new religion. My question here specifically is about prayers, my parents are very narrow-minded who hate to hear any thing about new Muslims, so how can they know that their daughter has entered Islam!? So I am hiding my faith, hence the problem, as I can't pray at our very small home where everyone's move is felt. Once my mother saw me praying, and from that moment she is monitoring me very closely restricting my behavior.when im working i got more space to do namaz now i lost my job.while sitting in home it is difficult to perform namaz,otherwise I have to pray laying down or sitting or alike. My situation is very complex, sometimes I start praying then suddenly stop it pretending as doing something else once hearing my mother's voice, what's your advice?
Also, what's ruling on necessity of covering face and hands during praying, is it compulsory in general? What about it in my special case? Are my prayers accepted without covering face and hands?
I want to add a fact about me, I am facing multi problems and difficulties so I find in praying an outlet and great relief to myself, just entering Salat (prayers) supplicating to Allah, I feel immediately relaxation and chest delight, and hope comes back again. 
Kindly advice as I don't have muslim friends except one or two muslims who are not much of Islamic following and religiousness, nor have I a nearby place where I can learn about Islam, only Internet. By the way, thanks a lot for your useful site and great favor you do for people.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. As to your question please have in mind that we are neither a fatwa site, even if we may display and explain fatwas and we are no peer support, so advice-requests are hardly on-topic. Basically covering your body except with hands and face (some may add feets) is required for salat, but there's also the ruling saying: necessity allows what is prohibited, but only a scholar or a fatwa can be a basis of an answer of your inquiry.

Comment: @JUNA JIJI What might the consequence be if you openly tell your parents that you are a Muslim now and that you will perform prayers? Would they harm you? Or kick out of the house? I understand you respect and fear them, but it is better to tell them openly. They may get angry and vent for some time (maybe a long time), but if you show your sincere dedication to being a Muslim, they may eventually accept it, and if God wills, they may also become Muslims because of you. May God give you ease in your difficulties.